# Increase Image Load Speed in Cube Portfolio Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, image-gallery, portfolio

Is there a way i can increase the load times for the images in cube gallery.  Can i also do that by limiting load times to what appears in the current view port and then loading further once page scrolls down. How can i achieve that. ? At the moment looks like the images are pre loaded once the site is loaded but i will like to do that sequentially instead of it loaded all images at once and at a higher tempo. 
I have been playing around with the displayType & displayTypeSpeed classes in the cube documentation here https://www.derecho.unam.mx/estudiantes/pagina/documentation/#options but not too sure if it is the right option to tweak.
As a point of reference check the speed  here on this page http://tile.johnzuh.com/messe2018/ to test for yourself.

Comment: I just accessed the site, and it is only loading the images once I scroll down. Perhaps what is happening for you, is that the images are in your web browser cache. Try clearing the cache then reloading the site to see the loading.

Comment: @geometrikal. Thanks for the tip. Just did that didn't notice any difference though since i had cleared my cache a few hours ago already. Well It loads in some cases per current viewport as you can see but in some cases not since i have several galleries on the same site. In any case do you have some tips on how i can optimise the speed of the load time in the current window.

Comment: @geometrikal Further tests on the various filters indicates one will have to click a particular filter (i.e menus e.g INSPIRATION1 tab ) twice or thrice before it loads respective images. Sometimes nothing happens at all and one has to wait for a while before trying again until the images under the category loads. Try it yourself if you have the chance. Propose solutions if possible.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this. You might have better luck contacting the plugin developers. But for me, the pages load fine, no having to click more than one time... Maybe the source images are too big?

Comment: @geometrikal Plugin Developer has recommended using some other animation types which might not require a longer time to load. Will try them and update accordingly. Now the decision will be made between trading off a fancy animation for performance

Comment: @geometrikal Got it sorted with the plugin developer. Appreciate the inputs anyway

Comment: That is nice to hear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted out with Plugin Developer. Opted for another animation effect which didnt require a long time to load in browser.

Comment: did you just used "default" for the "displayType" option and your issue was solved ?

Comment: @HHF In my case animationType = 'quicksand' did it for me. I decided to opt out on the fancy animations :). Maybe you can try it too

Comment: @HHF In my case animationType = 'quicksand' did it for me. I decided to opt out on the fancy animations :). Maybe you can try it too.  As for "displayType" i did "lazyLoading" and  typeSpeed was set to "5"  .

Comment: I realised also that the plugin loads all images in particular gallery before it sets the filters. A way to work around this is not to use the all filter from the beginning but instead define your default filter by asking it to select only particular images from onset. This could be a great workaround. I have had challenges going around the all filter preloads when hardcoding the gallery. Maybe this could help